# hosting multiple websites addresses without www in them go to the wrong website using host headers

Tags: web, header, host

I am hosting 2 websites each site as been created using 2 host bindings. with the same IP and different host name "www.host.com" and "host.com".

Call them website1 and website2

when I type in my browser www.website1.com or website1.com I am directed to website1

when I type in my browser www.website2.com  I am directed to website2

when I type in my browser website2.com I am directed to website1 and not website2 as expected

I can't figure out how to make website2.com without the www go to website2

Does any one know how?

Comment: What webserver are you running? apache? nginx?  This actually might be a better question for serverfault.com, the sys-admin analogue to this site but I might be able to help with a little more info

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your server is linux / apache, your can use rewrites to do the trick. If you already have a .htaccess file on your site add the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

#redirect website2.com to www.website2.com

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website2.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you don't already have one, create a new .htaccess file at the same directory level as your home page. Permissions  RW- R-- R-- should be good.

[Here's more info](http://wiki.lunarpages.com/Create_htaccess) on how to create a .htaccess file if you are new to this.

Good luck!